# django howto include urls from 3rd party app as nested in a project namespace

Tags: django, url

My project has a namespace 'dashboard' and I'd like to include a 3rd party app (django-calendar) into it, so my urls would be like `/dashboard/calendar-list`.

So in dashboard **urls.py** I added:

```
(...)
    path("avoirs/", include(avoirs_urls)),
    path("vouchers/", include(vouchers_urls)),
    path("logs/", include(log_urls)),
    path('schedule', include('schedule.urls', namespace='schedule')),
(...)
```

So I can reverse my urls using for example:

```
reverse("dashboard:schedule:calendar_list")
```

It's where I came accross a pitfall:

All the 3rd party app code uses urls like **calendar_list** instead of **schedule:calendar_list**. Same for templates using code like **{% url 'calendar_list' %}**.

It doesn't seem reasonable to refactor all the calendar app to fit my project. Is there a way to include it in the existing namespace? What's the guideline here? Thanks to share knowledge...

Comment: Not entirely clear from your question if `calendar-list` is your own app or a 3rd party app you're integrating in? Good practice is to set `app_name` in the `urls.py` for all your own apps - this is then the namespace you use.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the original post. I use a 3rd party app and the `app_name` is **schedule**.

Comment: OK, the app docs should tell you what names to use then. But I'd have thought `schedule:calendar_list` should work. 

If this is `django-schedular` though, I just checked the code, and they don't set `app_name` in the urls.py, so .. sorry. You'll just have to live with it.

Comment: So if their models have `get_absolute_url()` that reverse on a simple `calendar_list`, it means that I have to rewrite all their code?

Comment: You could submit a PR to their project I guess. Otherwise just use `reverse('calendar_list')` - is this a problem? (I mean, I feel people should namespace their apps, but other than that, it should be fine).

Comment: Right, I'd suggest a PR as it solves my issue.

Comment: Probably won't get approved though as it could break existing code for other people. Just avoid making anything "calendar_list" and you should be fine :)

Comment: @michjnich Sure, but I'm very confused about the strategy to adopt since it's not only an issue with a `calendar-list` view, it's all the application that makes extensive use of reversing urls from simple view name (all `get_absolute_url` in models, a lot in templatetags, etc.). Also, defining an `app_name` has been helpfull only for importing urls. It doesn't help on the way their models or templatetags resolve urls.